# Resume duplicates (variables) in to one cell

Tags: excel, formula

In the image I resume a little bit what I need, the names will be different but repetitive, so I need to resume in a second cell the names.

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: You can use `Advance Filter` to extract unique values. Also there are formulas to do automatically.

Comment: I found a solution, another is with option INDEX but I think is better with VBA to avoid many formulas inside a range of cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution with VBA, assuming columns are A and B

```
Sub findDuplicates()
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

Sheets("Viajes").Range("A3:A" & lastrow).AdvancedFilter _
Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
CopyToRange:=Sheets("Viajes").Range("B3"), _
Unique:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: It is just vba form of advance filter, what I suggested. You can do it from advance filter manually.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I got your question right, but if you want unique values from a column,
try copying the data to a new column and then data --> data tools --> remove duplicates